# infinite loop in stack implementation c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

this is my first data structure program. I am implementing a simple stack using array with push, pop and initialize functions. I am getting an infinite loop as the output. Could you please tell me why is this so?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
# define SIZE 6

class stack{



    public:
        void init();
        void push(int i);
        int pop();
        int top;
        int stck[SIZE];//bydefault private

};

void stack::init()
{
    top=0;
    return;
}

void stack::push(int i)
{

    if(top==SIZE)
    {
        cout<<"stack is full";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        top=top+1;
        stck[top]= i;
        return;
    }
} 

int stack::pop()
{
    if(top==0)
    {
        cout<<"stack is empty. \n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        top = top-1;
        return(stck[top-1]);
    }
} 

int main()
{
    stack stack1;
    stack1.init();
    int a;
    int m;


    while(a!=4)
    {

        cout<<"1. push 2. pop 3.display 4.exit .\n";
    cin>>a;



    if(a==1){
        cout<< "enter value";
        cin>>m;
        stack1.push(m);
    }
    if(a==2)
    {
        cout<<"popped"<< stack1.pop();

    }
    if(a==3)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<=stack1.top;k++)
        {
            cout<<stack1.stck[k];

        }
    }

   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think there's infinite loop?

Comment: You should use private fields and constructors, if you write an own class.

Comment: You would never wear a dirty shirt if you went to the public, so please present well formatted code in the public. Using of macros for constants is discouraged, use `const` variables instead. Also the use of `using namespace std;` is discouraged, it leads to name conflicts.

Comment: don't get dishurtened by down-votes .It's because it might not fit site's Q/A policy.

Answer (score 5):

You never initialize `a`, so your program has undefined behaviour.  Specifically, the `while (a != 4)` line performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `a` while its value is indeterminate, which the C++ standard explicitly states as undefined behaviour in section 4.1.

However, I doubt this is causing the issue at hand.  In practice, unless the optimizer just optimized all your code out, your program should usually behave as expected; it's only when `a == 4` on the first loop that you have problems.  This doesn't make the code acceptable, but there's probably more to it.

I suspect the problem is that you use `top` to represent one past the number of elements.  When you have zero elements, you point to the first; when you have one, you point to the second, etc.  This means you're pointing to the first unused element.

However, in both your `push` and `pop` functions, you change `top` first and only then access the stack, but acting as if you didn't change it:

```
top = top + 1;
stck[top] = i;
```

When your stack is empty, this will set `top` to 1 and then access `stck[1]`.  Meanwhile, `stck[0]` is left unset.  When popping, you have the opposite:

```
top = top - 1;
return stck[top-1];
```

This sets `top` back to 0, but returns `stck[-1]`, which is out of bounds.

I suspect that if you push `SIZE` values onto the stack, you will end up overwriting unrelated memory, which could cause all kinds of trouble.  I still don't see how an infinite loop will follow, but given the behaviour is undefined, it is certainly a possible result.

(The alternative is that you at some point enter something other than a number.  Seeing as you never check whether your input succeeded, if `a != 4` and you enter something invalid, all further reads will fail, and `a` will remain unequal to 4.  You could fix this by making changing your `while` to be

```
while (a != 4 && std::cin)
```

In that case, if you enter something invalid and `std::cin` goes into a non-good state, your loop (and thus program) will end.)

Comment: Well spotted. Typically you would use a do{}while() loop which evaluates the user input *after* the input ;-).

Comment: While(no pun intended) a valid statement, how does this enable an infinite loop to occur? If it does not (and I don't see how if could), this should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You only have a single loop, terminated based on user input.

If `cin>>a` fails, `a` will have whatever value it started with (undefined in your code), and you will loop on that unchanging value.

Typical ways for the input call to fail include

- pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on a *nix system)
- pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on a Windows system)
- redirected input from a pipe or file which is exhausted

There may be other causes of failed input as well.